# Good practice to send push notifications from my server?

Tags: php, push-notification

I have a messaging service on my app. I need to send push notifications each time someone sends a message. At least for iOS, I understood how it works : I do a job on my server each 30mn that request a new Apple Token. With this token refreshed every 30mn, i can send request to Apple server to send a push notif to the device token that I retrieved from client app.

Though, before I start developing all this, I want to know if there is a good practice to send all these notifications. I was thinking : if each message on my app sends a push notif, the "trivial" way to carry out this would be to create a socket within my PHP server and send a request to Apple for each request my client app does. We respond to our client app only when Apple responds to our push notif request.

However this solution may slow down tremendously my app, as each HTTP request from my client apps to my server has **to wait until Apple responds.**

Then, I was wondering if it would be better to just queue push notifs (in the database) when a request is done from my client to my server, and do a job each second that takes all the new push notifs that was queued the last second, in order to send them grouped to Apple, in one single request. Is it something commonly done ? Or maybe I overestimate the time Apple responds to each request ?

Comment: this question is based on opinions..

Comment: I’m expecting high traffic on my app, what solution choose big app to handle high volume of notification to send like this... I want to know if there are good practice before starting developing:)

Comment: "I'm expecting high traffic on my app, what solution to choose big app to handle high volume of notification to send like this ..." This you can find out on your own in courses, tutorial, List of option, comparative post. this forum is only to solve problem with Codes..

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. <= this is a close reason in Stack Overflow